# betareg fails to converge is dependent variable has more than 8 digits

Tags: r, betareg

I am having problems using the `betareg` package. When I try to run the model `m1`, the model does not converge. However, when I round `y` to 8 digits, it works well (127 iterations). See below for the code. Does anybody know why this tiny change as such a big influence on the model?
See code below.

```
#install.packages("betareg", dependencies=TRUE)
library(betareg)
data <- data.frame("x" = c(194, 194, 194,  73,  73,  73, 105, 105, 105, 222, 222, 222,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0),
                   "y" = c(0.9717500000, 0.9191161111, 0.9456172222, 0.0464116667, 0.0413683333, 0.034105555, 0.9178222222, 0.9661872222, 0.9619844444,
                           0.9576777778, 0.9710794444, 0.9562516667, 0.0277777778, 0.0277777778, 0.0277777778, 0.0277777778, 0.0277777778, 0.0277777778))


library(betareg)

m1 <-  betareg(formula = y ~ x, data = data, link = "cauchit", type = "ML")

m2 <-  betareg(formula = round(y,8) ~ x, data = data, link = "cauchit", type = "ML")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that this really has to do something with with the rounding. It's just that this is a small data set where `y` switches from very close to zero to very close to 1 if `x` is less or more than 100. Hence, the cauchit link is a bit challenging to optimize here. With the default settings it almost converges but any of the following modifications leads to successful convergence:

- use a log-link for the precision parameter
- increase the allowed iterations for the Fisher-Scoring
- use better starting values

Additionally, relaxing the strictness of the Fisher-Scoring as suggested in a previous answer by IRTFM would also lead to successful convergence.

Out of the options above I would always recommend to try out a log-link first because it typically improves inference about the precision parameter (e.g., coverage of Wald confidence intervals is better etc.). The only reason that this is not the default in `betareg()` is for backward compatibility with the first version of the R package and for consistency with the original Ferrari & Cribari Neto (2004) paper. But the log-link is the default when explicitly specifying a two-part formula, here just with an intercept:

```
m1 <- betareg(y ~ x | 1, data = data, link = "cauchit")
summary(m1)
## Call:
## betareg(formula = y ~ x | 1, data = data, link = "cauchit")
## 
## Standardized weighted residuals 2:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -1.6746 -1.1704 -0.4335  0.8269  1.9560 
## 
## Coefficients (mean model with cauchit link):
##              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept) -19.16562    3.62912  -5.281 1.28e-07 ***
## x             0.21393    0.03946   5.422 5.90e-08 ***
## 
## Phi coefficients (precision model with log link):
##             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept)   3.6936     0.3397   10.87   <2e-16 ***
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 
## 
## Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
## Log-likelihood: 31.22 on 3 Df
## Pseudo R-squared: 0.7941
## Number of iterations: 29 (BFGS) + 124 (Fisher scoring)
```

Using the corresponding coefficients as starting values then also leads to a successful convergence with an identity link:

```
s <- coef(m1)
s[3] <- exp(s[3])
m2 <- betareg(y ~ x, data = data, link = "cauchit", start = s)
summary(m2)
## Call:
## betareg(formula = y ~ x, data = data, link = "cauchit", start = s)
## 
## Standardized weighted residuals 2:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -1.6746 -1.1704 -0.4335  0.8269  1.9560 
## 
## Coefficients (mean model with cauchit link):
##              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
## (Intercept) -19.16562    3.62912  -5.281 1.28e-07 ***
## x             0.21393    0.03946   5.422 5.90e-08 ***
## 
## Phi coefficients (precision model with identity link):
##       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
## (phi)    40.19      13.65   2.944  0.00324 **
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 
## 
## Type of estimator: ML (maximum likelihood)
## Log-likelihood: 31.22 on 3 Df
## Pseudo R-squared: 0.7941
## Number of iterations: 1 (BFGS) + 2 (Fisher scoring)
```

As you see, the models are virtually identical with just a couple of additional Fisher-Scoring iterations, leading to the same coefficients and inference in the mean model.

Answer (score 5):

Since the point at which this infelicity occurs is exactly the point where the y values will differ from the values where it does not generate the warning by an amount comparable to the default value for `fstol` in `betareg.control`, I reasoned that there is some test of the difference of `y` versus an estimate of `y` that is not being met. I tried your code with the addition of a somewhat larger value for

> fstol ::
> numeric tolerance for convergence in (quasi) Fisher scoring.

```
... , control=betareg.control(fstol =1e-7)
```

And no warning appears. Since it doesn't throw an error I think you should call it an "infelicity" rather than a "bug" when you report this to the package author.

```
maintainer("betareg")
[1] "Achim Zeileis <Achim.Zeileis@R-project.org>"
```

He should be able to fix the test that generates this warning. (I'm not able to figure out which of those conditions are being met or unmet.) Here's the testing code>

```
if ((fsmaxit == 0 & opt$convergence > 0) | iter >= fsmaxit) {
    converged <- FALSE
    warning("optimization failed to converge")
```

I tried playing around with other values for `fsmaxit` in the `betareg.control` values, but wasn't able to narrow down the problem yet. I wondered if the second nested term in the logical tests should be:

```
opt$convergence > fstol
```

.... but didn't think that it was likely that R's `optim` would work that way.

Comment: As a brief explanation for the convergence diagnostic: By default, `betareg()` first runs BFGS optimization via `optim()` based on analytical gradients and subsequently a custom Fisher scoring with analytical gradients and Hessian. Thus, the first conditions checks whether Fisher-Scoring is switched off (`fxmaxit == 0`) and `optim()` did not converge (`convergence > 0`). The second condition checks whether the `iter`ations in the Fisher-Scoring exceeding the maximum (`fsmaxit`) without attaining the desired precision/convergence. Thus, the latter is the culprit for the example data.